# Why is the cyclic volume integral of $P/T$ larger than the one of $P_{ext}/T$ in an irreversible process?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, carnot-cycle

In order to derive the Clasius inequality we can call the first law of thermodynamics in it's differential form:

$$dU={\itđ}q-P_{ext}dV.$$

If the process is reversible:

$$dU={\itđ}q_{rev}-PdV.$$

Substracting both equations:

$${\itđ}q_{rev}-{\itđ}q=(P-P_{ext})dV.$$

Dividing by $T$ and taking the cyclic integral:
$$\oint\frac{{\itđ}q_{rev}}{T}-\oint\frac{{\itđ}q}{T}=\oint\frac{P-P_{ext}}{T}dV.$$
The first term corrsponds to the cylcic intgral of $dS$ thus itn vanishes. After some algebra:
$$\oint\frac{{\itđ}q}{T}=\oint\frac{P_{ext}}{T}dV-\oint\frac{P}{T}dV.$$
The Clasius theorem states that:
$$\oint\frac{{\itđ}q}{T}\le0$$
Which for the above equation means:
$$\oint\frac{P}{T}dV\ge\oint\frac{P_{ext}}{T}dV.$$

How can this inequality be proved without resorting to the concept of entropy?

Comment: The infinitesimal form of the first law  for a $PVT$ system is $dU=\delta Q-PdV$ regardless of the transformation.

Comment: You're right, thank you. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was misleading. The problem was not the sign, that is just a convention (it just happens that I'm more used to the minus sign for the work). The problem was that I don't understand why you replace $P$ with $P_{ext}$ in the case of a general process.

Comment: I think the convention is about the sign associated to the symbol $w$ for work. But your expression is right regardless of the convention. Which makes a lot of difference for the question at hand. Now, work is the action of/on the system on/by the surroundings so the acting pressure is the external one. $P$ without subscript stands for the internal pressure, which is equal to the external one only if the process is reversible.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's $-PdV$ regardless of the convention. My bad! But the comment was right anyway...Regarding the pressure, I think it is a rather subtle matter: I'd say that $P=P_{ext}$ is valid for a quasi-static transformation, in general. The problem is that while all reversible transformations are quasi-static, a quasi-static transformation can be irreversible...

Comment: Yes. But if the process is not quasi-static, the equality doesn't hold. And work will always be $-P_{exp}dV$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48539/discussion-between-valerio92-and-geoart).

Answer (score 1):

Let's talk about reversible and irreversible processes.

**Irreversible Processes**
In an irreversible process, temperature and pressure typically vary with spatial position within the system, so there is no single value we can assign to either the system temperature or the system pressure. So we can't use the equation of state for the gas (e.g., the ideal gas law) to establish the relationship between pressure, volume, and temperature of the system for an irreversible process. In addition to this, because of gas viscous effects, the pressure at the boundary of the system where work is being done (e.g., the piston face) depends not only on the system volume, but also on the time rate of change of volume.  In a rapid irreversible deformation, this can contribute significantly to the force at the boundary and to the rate at which work is being done at the boundary.  Irrespective of whether the process is irreversible or reversible, at the boundary where work is being done (e.g., the piston face), the gas pressure will always precisely match the so-called external pressure $P_{ext}$ applied at the boundary.  That is, pressure is continuous at the boundary.  And this pressure can always be used to calculate the amount of work.

There is also often heat flow occurring across part of the boundary of the system.  As with the pressure, the gas temperature at the boundary precisely matches the external temperature (of the surroundings) $T_{ext}$.  And, although it is not very widely known, in applying the Clausius inequality, one should always be using this boundary temperature (across which the heat transfer is occurring) in calculating the right hand side of the Clausius inequality.  That is, $$\Delta S\geq \int{\frac{dq}{T_{ext}}}$$  One cannot use T, because it is both non-uniform and unknown (except in the initial and final states of the system).

**Reversible Processes** In reversible processes, the temperature and pressure are uniform throughout the system, and viscous effects are negligible, so the average temperature and pressure of the gas are equal to the values of temperature and pressure at the boundaries where heat transfer and work are occurring, and the ideal gas law can be applied. In this case, for the Clausius inequality, the equal sign applies.

**Summary**

In an irreversible process, the average gas pressure and the average gas temperature do not match the values at the boundaries.  But the gas pressure and gas temperature at the boundaries precisely match the values for the surroundings.  We call these values $P_{ext}$ and $T_{ext}$.  It is these values that should always be used in our equations for calculating the amount of work done by the gas on the surroundings and for applying the Clausius inequality.  For an irreversible process, the average gas pressure and the average gas temperature match the values at the boundaries, and can thus be used to calculate the work and to apply the Clausius inequality.

Comment: I get your point and totally agree with you. However I think this is more a comment on the notation than an actual answer to the question.

Comment: @GeoArt Directly comparing a reversible path to an irreversible path between two thermodynamic equilibrium states of a system is, in my judgment, not a very fruitful pursuit.  The reversible path does not have to bear any significant resemblance to the irreversible path, aside from passing between the two end states.  For example, in the case of an adiabatic irreversible process, it is not possible to conceive of an adiabatic reversible path that passes between the two end states.  Devising a reversible process may also even involve imposing different paths to different parts of the system.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this question as stated doesn't make sense. However the derivation as set makes perfect sense with a slight difference.
After getting rid of the cyclic integral corresponding to entropy we're left with:
$$\oint\frac{{\itđ}q}{T}=\oint\frac{P_{ext}-P}{T}dV$$
For a given infinitesimal contribution to the integral at the rhs, if $P_{ext}-P>0$ the system will be spontaneously compressed and $dV<0$, while if $P_{ext}-P<0$ the system will spontaneously expand and $dV>0$, therefore
$$\left(P_{ext}-P\right)dV\le0$$
will be true throughout the whole cycle. Then:
$$\oint\frac{{\itđ}q}{T}\le0$$
qed

Answer (score 0):

Here is another reason why it doesn't make much sense to directly compare reversible and irreversible paths between two thermodynamic equilibrium states of a closed system.  Suppose that, for the irreversible path, the initial equilibrium state is A and the final equilibrium state is B.  Are you aware that there are an infinite number of reversible paths that can be traversed between these same two thermodynamic equilibrium states?  All these reversible paths will have exactly the same $\Delta U$, $\Delta S$, and $q_{rev}-w_{rev}$ as for the irreversible path, but the total heat transferred $q_{rev}$ and the total work done $w_{rev}$ will differ from path to path.  Some of the paths can have very large values of $q_{rev}$ and $w_{rev}$ while others can have values comparable to those for the irreversible path.

Comment: I agree with almost everything. But, why wouldn't it be worth it to find some general characteristic about the differences?

Comment: Besides isn't that exactly one of the pieces of information that can be extracted from the Clasius theorem?

Comment: @GeoArt It wouldn't be worth it to find some general characteristics about the differences because the reversible path is not unique.  So you would be comparing one irreversible path with an infinite number of possible reversible paths between the same two end states.  And a large fraction of these reversible paths would be extremely different from the irreversible path.  Certainly, differentially, a selected reversible path could be much more intricate (and all over the place) compared to an irreversible path.

Comment: I don't get your point. So what if they're different or infinite? Since they are reversible, all of them share some features that irreversible processes don't.

Comment: I can see comparing the total path integrals between the initial and final states separately, but putting the path integrals for the irreversible path and a reversible path into the same equation under the same integral sign, in my judgment, makes no sense.